# What happens when a multi-dimensional array is accessed using only one index?

Tags: multidimensional-array, vb6

I need to read and understand the source code of a Visual Basic 6 application. I'm new to the language and the code is quite poorly written, so I often have a hard time telling if a surprising line of code does something smart in an incomprehensible way, or simply something mundane in a bad way. I also lack a build environment to do simple trials in, so I've had to rely on search engines and online tutorials, but in this case none of them have provided an answer.

The code which has me stumped looks like this:

```vb
Sub ArrayFunction()
    Dim Arr(1 To 3, 1 To 5) As Double
    Arr(1, 1) = 11
    Arr(1, 2) = 22
    Arr(1, 3) = 33
    Arr(1, 4) = 44
    Arr(1, 5) = 55
    Call InnerFunction(Arr())
End Sub

Sub InnerFunction(Arr() As Double)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        OtherFunction(CLng(Arr(i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

I need to figure out what values `OtherFunction` are called with, so I wonder, what happens when you index into a multi-dimensional array using only one index?

Comment: Nothing happens. VB6 will throw a `Error 9, Subscript out of range` error on the line `OtherFunction(CLng(Arr(i)))`. So whatever you're looking at - it's _not_ working code.

Comment: Having a Sub called Function can be confusing I would add.

Comment: Interestingly enough, VB won't barf on the call to UBound; in the absence of the optional Dimension argument, UBound returns the upper bound of the first index.  However, it does still crash on the OtherFunction call, as Hel O'Ween described.

Note that the code could still be working (scarily badly) if the function is wrapped in an On Error {Resume Next | GoTo | ...}, including several function calls above...

Comment: If you compile without the array bounds check optimization and remove LBound/UBound and just go from 0 to total elements - 1, then you can access all the elements in a multi-dimension array as a one-dimension array.

Comment: Turns out that the outer subroutine isn't called at all, but instead a nigh identical copy of it which takes Arr as an argument is. At the call site, the array is mono-dimensional, explaining the lack of errors.

Comment: @KellyEthridge were you referring to "Advanced Optimizations > Remove Array Bounds Checks" ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz yes I am.